# How can I save a Message in Discord with Python, in a simple variable

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Hello Stackoverflow Community,

I wanted to write a Discord-Bot in Python, which should solve simple Mathquestions, like: "Whats 55+40?". The Questions are asked from another bot and the structure of the Question is everytime the same. I wrote a Calculator and it works and i just need the input from a private message(not a server). I do not need to show any code, because I dont have some and I need to start at the described situation to save the messages in a variable, so my Question is:

How can I import **private messages** from Discord, to **save** them in a normal variable, like x?

I use Sublime Text

Thanks for answers!

Comment: How do you run commands? Via the `on_message` event?

Comment: No via sublime Text.

Comment: Ah, I think you've misunderstood. I don't mean your text-editor, but how the bot processes commands. Do you see `async def on_message(message)` somewhere in your code?

Comment: No i dont have any code I just have a simple Python Calculator, what has nothing to do with discord and I dont know anything about the discord Líbary and I want to know, how to import just the messages. Can you help me? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the comments of the question it is clear that you don't have any code for a bot yet. Look at [this quickstart guide](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html) to set up a bot. Once set up, all messages typed to the bot (also DM messages) will trigger the `on_message` event. You can then save the contents of the message into a variable like so

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    messageContent = message.content
```

Comment: Ahh thanks. If i will have any other questions, i will ask you here.

Comment: I dont get, whats wrong. I just copied the Quickstart code and dont Changed anything. I think i need another Token. What is a Token? Thanks

Comment: Visit [Discord Developer Portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications), create an application, set it as bot user and copy the token unter `Bot`

Comment: Can i use my token, because i getting the questions

Comment: If you have a token you will need to place this into the `client.run(TOKEN)` function

Comment: I know, but can i use my personal Token, that it works with my account?

Answer (score 0):

i assume what you mean is waiting for a user to reply to a certain message from the bot, you can get your bot to private message someone by doing something like this:

```
user = ctx.author
await user.send("Hello, world!")
```

now, for your bot waiting for a reply for your user, in your code, you will need a check just to make sure only the bot is waiting for a message from the specific person (even in dms) by creating a check function:

```
        def check(m):
            return m.author.id == ctx.author.id
```

then after using user.send to send a message, or an embed, add

```
 message = await bot.wait_for('message', check=check, timeout=120)
```

which means the bot waits until the user sends their answer (waits 120 seconds in this example)

then, to get the **content** of the message you just want to do make a variable called content or answer and set it to message.content ( content = message.content )

Comment: I mean my bot sould answer another bot. I will get an message (Simple math equation) and my bot should save it and message back

Comment: you will still need to get the `message.content` either way to get the message's content, checking is just a good way to make sure the correct person is responding. also, discord.py docs has a bot setup [guide](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html) to help you out, as it seems you haven't made a bot yet.

Comment: I made a bot, but not with Discord. Thanks for the quickstart